# How can I get VirtIO network drivers working on FreeNAS or NAS4Free KVM host?

Tags: virtualization, freebsd, kvm-virtualization, network-attached-storage, truenas

I'm trying to run either FreeNAS 8.0.4 or NAS4Free 9  as a KVM guest on my Ubuntu 12.04 (server) but the network connection is unusably slow in either guest OS (when testing with rsync for example the connection starts off normal, at around 100MB/s, but then quickly fluctuates to 2MB/s tops).

With NAS4Free I can use the e1000 (which doesn't work with FreeNAS) but it doesn't make any difference.

Bridge networking is setup on the host and I've also tested the hard drive read write speeds within the host to make sure that wasn't where the bottleneck was coming from.

I'm thinking that installing the VirtIO drivers may fix the problem, assuming there isn't some network setting I could have messed up on the host which is causing this?

However, I can't seem to figure out how to install VirtIO on either FreeNAS or NAS4Free. Since NAS4Free is based on FreeBSD 9 I started with this [tutorial](http://viktorpetersson.com/2012/01/16/how-to-upgrade-freebsd-8-2-to-freebsd-9-0-with-virtio/) but even though NAS4Free is based on FreeBSD 9 it doesn't seem to be a full install?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by asking in the mailing lists of the communities - nobody knows what has been removed from the distribution better than its developers. 
FreeNAS mailing lists: http://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=151951
NAS4Free bug tracker list: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=722987&atid=2914048